# Creating Maven Web Service on Tomcat

Tags: web-services, maven, tomcat, netbeans

I created a Maven web application which name is "aa3" on Netbeans. I choose Tomcat server which Netbeans installed. And then I added a web service class. A warning appeared, it says:

[image]

I choose Yes.
Then I run my project but it did not work.

Outputs are:
aa3

```
cd /home/ekcdr/NetBeansProjects/aa3; JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle /home/ekcdr/netbeans-7.3/java/maven/bin/mvn -Dnetbeans.deploy=true -Dnetbeans.deploy.clientUrlPart=/NewWebService package
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building aa3 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

[dependency:copy]

[resources:resources]
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/ekcdr/NetBeansProjects/aa3/src/main/resources

[compiler:compile]
Compiling 1 source file to /home/ekcdr/NetBeansProjects/aa3/target/classes

[resources:testResources]
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/ekcdr/NetBeansProjects/aa3/src/test/resources

[compiler:testCompile]
No sources to compile

[surefire:test]
No tests to run.
Surefire report directory: /home/ekcdr/NetBeansProjects/aa3/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0


[war:war]
Packaging webapp
Assembling webapp [aa3] in [/home/ekcdr/NetBeansProjects/aa3/target/aa3-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Processing war project
Copying webapp resources [/home/ekcdr/NetBeansProjects/aa3/src/main/webapp]
Webapp assembled in [79 msecs]
Building war: /home/ekcdr/NetBeansProjects/aa3/target/aa3-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 8.208s
Finished at: Fri May 24 19:06:43 EEST 2013
Final Memory: 16M/132M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
NetBeans: Deploying on Apache Tomcat 7.0.34.0
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
Starting Tomcat process...
Waiting for Tomcat...
Tomcat server started.
Undeploying ...
OK - Undeployed application at context path /aa3
In-place deployment at /home/ekcdr/NetBeansProjects/aa3/target/aa3-1.0-SNAPSHOT
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2Ftmp%2Fcontext6381208068383234000.xml&path=/aa3
FAIL - Deployed application at context path /aa3 but context failed to start
The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.performDeploy(ExecutionChecker.java:178)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.executionResult(ExecutionChecker.java:130)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.execute.MavenCommandLineExecutor.run(MavenCommandLineExecutor.java:212)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
```

Apache Tomcat 7.0.34.0 Log

```
May 24, 2013 4:50:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:657)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:536)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1462)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:792)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1445)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:860)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:357)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

May 24, 2013 4:50:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
May 24, 2013 4:50:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1256)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:376)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

May 24, 2013 4:50:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
```

Apache Tomcat 7.0.34.0

```
May 24, 2013 7:06:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/ekcdr/.netbeans/7.3/apache-tomcat-7.0.34.0_base
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/ekcdr/apache-tomcat-7.0.34
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/ekcdr/.netbeans/7.3/apache-tomcat-7.0.34.0_base/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/ekcdr/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/ekcdr/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/i386::/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
May 24, 2013 7:06:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8084"]
May 24, 2013 7:06:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 24, 2013 7:06:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2289 ms
May 24, 2013 7:06:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 24, 2013 7:06:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
May 24, 2013 7:06:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /home/ekcdr/.netbeans/7.3/apache-tomcat-7.0.34.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/d1.xml
May 24, 2013 7:06:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /home/ekcdr/NetBeansProjects/d1/target/d1-1.0-SNAPSHOT does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4906)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5086)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:657)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1637)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

May 24, 2013 7:06:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
May 24, 2013 7:06:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
May 24, 2013 7:06:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/d1] startup failed due to previous errors
May 24, 2013 7:06:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /home/ekcdr/.netbeans/7.3/apache-tomcat-7.0.34.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/aa2.xml
May 24, 2013 7:06:58 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate
SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/ha/store/api/BackingStoreException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/ha/store/api/BackingStoreException
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.<init>(ServletAdapter.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapterList.createHttpAdapter(ServletAdapterList.java:77)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapterList.createHttpAdapter(ServletAdapterList.java:53)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapterList.createAdapter(HttpAdapterList.java:77)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapterList.createAdapter(HttpAdapterList.java:71)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:266)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:152)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate(WSServletContextListener.java:131)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(WSServletContainerInitializer.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5274)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:657)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1637)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.ha.store.api.BackingStoreException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 22 more

May 24, 2013 7:06:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/aa2] startup failed due to previous errors
May 24, 2013 7:06:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /home/ekcdr/.netbeans/7.3/apache-tomcat-7.0.34.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/d6_tc_yes.xml
May 24, 2013 7:06:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /home/ekcdr/NetBeansProjects/d6_tc_yes/target/d6_tc_yes-1.0-SNAPSHOT does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4906)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5086)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:657)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1637)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

May 24, 2013 7:06:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
May 24, 2013 7:06:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
May 24, 2013 7:06:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/d6_tc_yes] startup failed due to previous errors
May 24, 2013 7:06:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /home/ekcdr/.netbeans/7.3/apache-tomcat-7.0.34.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/aa1.xml
May 24, 2013 7:07:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/aa1] startup failed due to previous errors
May 24, 2013 7:07:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /home/ekcdr/.netbeans/7.3/apache-tomcat-7.0.34.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/deneme1.xml
May 24, 2013 7:07:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /home/ekcdr/NetBeansProjects/deneme1/target/deneme1-1.0-SNAPSHOT does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4906)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5086)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:657)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1637)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

May 24, 2013 7:07:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
May 24, 2013 7:07:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
May 24, 2013 7:07:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/deneme1] startup failed due to previous errors
May 24, 2013 7:07:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /home/ekcdr/.netbeans/7.3/apache-tomcat-7.0.34.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml
May 24, 2013 7:07:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /home/ekcdr/.netbeans/7.3/apache-tomcat-7.0.34.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/a1.xml
May 24, 2013 7:07:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /home/ekcdr/NetBeansProjects/a1/build/web does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4906)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5086)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:657)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1637)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

May 24, 2013 7:07:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
May 24, 2013 7:07:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
May 24, 2013 7:07:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/a1] startup failed due to previous errors
May 24, 2013 7:07:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /home/ekcdr/.netbeans/7.3/apache-tomcat-7.0.34.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml
May 24, 2013 7:07:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /home/ekcdr/.netbeans/7.3/apache-tomcat-7.0.34.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/aa3.xml
May 24, 2013 7:07:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/aa3] startup failed due to previous errors
May 24, 2013 7:07:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /home/ekcdr/.netbeans/7.3/apache-tomcat-7.0.34.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/deneme2.xml
May 24, 2013 7:07:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /home/ekcdr/NetBeansProjects/deneme2/build/web does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4906)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5086)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:657)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1637)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

May 24, 2013 7:07:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
May 24, 2013 7:07:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
May 24, 2013 7:07:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/deneme2] startup failed due to previous errors
May 24, 2013 7:07:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8084"]
May 24, 2013 7:07:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 24, 2013 7:07:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 13561 ms
May 24, 2013 7:07:03 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase stop
INFO: The stop() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/aa3]] after stop() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
May 24, 2013 7:07:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deleteRedeployResources
INFO: Undeploying context [/aa3]
May 24, 2013 7:07:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /home/ekcdr/.netbeans/7.3/apache-tomcat-7.0.34.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/aa3.xml
May 24, 2013 7:07:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/aa3] startup failed due to previous errors
```

What is the problem in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy ha-api.jar to your Tomcat/lib regardless if your project is bundled with jaxb-api or not (Mine is).